# Delete duplicates on condition

Tags: excel, vba

This is what I have:
[image]

I want to get the duplicates, which would be apple and pear. The macro should delete the most expensive apple and pear and if the duplicates have the same price just delete one of the duplicated items.

The result should be this:

[image]

Comment: Please include the code you are using for this in your question and explain the problem you ran into.

Comment: @braX i haven't created anything yet,because i don't know where to start.Its my first time trying to work with duplicates and when googling i couldn't find relevant info for this

Comment: Well please keep in mind that Stack Overflow is meant to help you will your existing code, not to simply write it all for you. I would start with learning how to loop through rows if you want to use that approach.

Comment: Based on the example you do not need VBA to do this. First sort the list by column1 and column2 and then remove the duplicates. If you have sorted the list in the right way you will get the desired result.

Comment: alright thanks man i'll try to create it and where i get stuck i'll ask for help !

Comment: @Storax alright i'll check it

Comment: Have you made a Hello World macro? Do you have any experience with macros at all?

Comment: @RossSymonds Yeah i have been using vba for a few months now,but never tried anything with duplicates and tried googling how to do this but couldn't find anything really

Comment: This would also be simple with `Power Query` if you have Excel 2010 or later.  Merely `Group By` the fruit column, and select the `Min` operation on the Cost column.

Comment: @Ron Rosenfeld: Yes, just tried and works, of course. And certainly better than my suggestion. Just too many tools in Excel to know ;-)

Comment: Thanks Everyone I was able to find 2 methods on how i could do this!                             I was stuck with this for weeks can't believe how easy it was

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you are working with thousands of rows of data or are going to do the process everyday then creating a macro is probably overkill. If you do need a macro then hopefully you can modify this code below.

```
Sub HighestPrice()
For a = 2 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For b = a + 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    If Range("A" & a).Value = Range("A" & b).Value Then
        
        If Range("B" & a).Value >= Range("B" & b).Value Then
            Range("B" & a).ClearContents
            Range("A" & a).ClearContents
        Else
            Range("B" & b).ClearContents
            Range("A" & b).ClearContents
        
        End If
    End If
    
Next b

Next a

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks man and yeah the reason i wanted a macro for this is because its about 600 rows weekly that have to be cleaned

Comment: Thanks @Ross Symonds i was able to use ur answer and modify it a bit and got what i wanted.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way to start would be to sort by amount small to large then by fruit. Then all you need to do is loop through each fruit, if the value matches previous delete row.
If you use the record macro to get the sort, then use a for loop like this

```
Dim cCell as range ''moving cell

Dim rng as range ''range of fruit

Dim previousCell as string


Set rng = range("A1:A10") ''range of fruit


For each cCell in rng

  If cCell.value = previousCell then 

    cCell.EntireRow.Delete

  Else

    previousCell=cCell.value

  End if

Next cCell
```

Comment: Hey,i just tested this and it worked :D                                                                                       Thanks i sadly cant give 2 people the correct answer but ur method works as well

Comment: No worries, Ross gave a better answer as he also included how to handle changing range size. If your macro starts to take a while add
 Application.screenupdating=false

To beginning, as this stops the screen from changing until the end of the macro, speeding it up loads